# Android Loading Dialog Set Background with Custom Layout

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

I want to create a processing dialog with an oval rectangle same as the picture below. However, the layout is still a square which looked a bit strange.
Great if anyone would provide a solution for me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: where is the square?

Comment: @Kalem: Yes you are right. I searched several times in google but would not find that question. Many thanks for your help !